# What is the URL_CHANGED Event on IIS7 Request Tracing Log?

Tags: php, iis, url-rewriting, trace, logging

I just enabled [Failed Request Tracing](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/467/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules/) for a site and I get a URL_CHANGED event as the third item on the log.

```
1. GENERAL_REQUEST_START SiteId="1", AppPoolId="DefaultAppPool", ConnId="1610613013", RawConnId="0", RequestURL="http://example.com:80/test/wp-admin/", RequestVerb="GET" 15:35:54.176 
2. GENERAL_SET_REQUEST_HEADER HeaderName="AspFilterSessionId", HeaderValue="", Replace="true" 15:35:54.192 
3. URL_CHANGED OldUrl="/test/wp-admin/", NewUrl="/index.php/test/wp-admin/" 15:35:54.192
```

Can someone tell me where the **URL_CHANGED** event comes from and how I can prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say this might be a question for the stackoverflow sister site [serverfault.com](http://WWW.serverfault.com)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip... http://serverfault.com/questions/7247/what-is-the-urlchanged-event-on-iis7-request-tracing-log

Comment: Unfortunately no acceptable answer on serverfault yet but I accept this answer anyway because I guess it points to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me yesterday. In the end, when I enabled Failed Request Tracing logs for all areas in IIS, I could see that it was actually being changed in an ISAPI filter.